# TFS CI across multible build agents (with batch changes option)

Tags: tfs, build, continuous-integration

Exploring upgrade to on premise TFS 2017.3
We have a large project that takes about 20-30 minutes to compile. I'm planning on setting up multiple build agents on different servers to handle compilations on every check-in.
I enabled Continues Integration trigger and can run builds on all 10 agents in parallel (triggered by check-in). When I continue to check in files, the builds just put in queue waiting for agents to complete previous builds.
Selecting "Batch changes while a build is in progress" checkbox allows only one build to run even if I have 9 more agents ready for work.

How can I use all 10 agents and butch changes only when all of them are being used?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior, take a look at the behavior of "Batch changes" of Continuous Integration

> **Batch changes**
>
> Select this check box if you have a lot of team members uploading
>   changes often and you want to reduce the number of builds you are
>   running. **If you select this option, when a build is running, the
>   system waits until the build is completed and then queues another
>   build of all changes that have not yet been built.**
>
> You can batch changes when your code is in Git in the project or on
>   GitHub. This option is not available if your code is in a remote Git
>   repo or in Subversion.

If you selected this option, then you will have to wait the build completed and queue another build.  More details please take a look at the official [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/build/triggers?view=vsts&tabs=designer#batch-changes).